# web parts in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-parts

This might be the most trivial question asked, but I raise it again. Am planning to get started with asp.net MVC on a personal project and here am struck if it supports webparts or any other alternative to it is present. I intend to have a start page similar to igoogle or pageflakes, but my initial research pointed out that as there's no ViewState nor Postback concepts in ASP.NET MVC implementing web parts is not possible.

If that is the case, are there any resources which helps in building a start page as the one i wish to using MVC.

PS: Links I found in the initial research

1. [Quick tips on asp.net MVC -
   webparts framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/16/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-webpart-framework.aspx)
2. [Building widgets using jquery in
   asp.net MVC](http://lakkakula.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/developing-web-2-0-portal-using-asp-net-mvc-microsoft-ajax-client-templates-and-jquery-with-drag-and-drop-widget-personalization-part-1/)

Comment: The best option is AJAX.

Comment: Just create PartialViews, and use Ajax to load the content.

Comment: @SLaks: do you recommend to go with jquery and tools to build the app?

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to create widgets that can interact with the server without reloading the page.
This way, the widgets will not affect each-other.

jQuery will be useful here.

---

Alternatively, you could put each widget in its own `<iframe>`.